# How to extract the loss history from sklearn SGDRegressor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm writing a q-learning algorithm with linear function approximator, the code looks like this:

```
for i in xrange(num_iter):

    idx = np.random.choice(N, batch_size)
    now_data = train_data[idx]

    predicted_value = regressor.predict(now_data["next_state"])    
    now_data["true_value"] = predicted_value + now_data["reward"]

    regressor.partial_fit(X=now_data["current_state"], y=now_data["true_value"])
```

Now I want to plot the loss during the training process, but I did not find any way to extract the loss history from `partial_fit` or `fit`, although the loss could be displayed on the screen when `verbose` is set.

I also surveyed `learning_curves`, but it does not seem to apply to this case because the label changes in each iteration.

Is there any method to do this?

Comment: No. In the current implementation, there is no attribute or method you can access which has this functionality.